# Lots of errors about http: TLS handshake error from <ip>:<port>: remote error: tls: bad certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubelet

I'm getting lots of errors on one of my K8s worker nodes saying "http: TLS handshake error from some_ip:port: remote error: tls: bad certificate", but I'm not having any problems using any of my K8s containers.  The problem is being logged in /var/log/syslog seems to be specific to one particular K8s node.

I assume I need to update a certificate, but I'm not sure if it's something in /etc/kubernetes/pki or /var/lib/kubelet/pki.

I assume it's related to the cni0 interface, since that's the subnet that matches the .

Does anybody know what it means, or better yet, how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The information you provided in not enough for me to infere what is the cause of this issue. Does the mentioned node is in Ready state? Can you also provide complete logs from kubelet?

Comment: The node is in a ready state.
The kubelet lots is almost entirely this message: 
Feb 19 11:50:02 bessie kubelet[31809]: I0219 11:50:02.644098   31809 log.go:181] http: TLS handshake error from 10.244.2.136:32964: remote error: tls: bad certificate 
It repeats every minute.

Comment: Well, the ip suggests its a pod IP (10.244.0.0/16). Run `kubectl get po -A -owide` to find out what pod it is.

Comment: That tells me it's the metrics server so obviously (now) that deployment is wrong.  I deleted the deployment, as I believe I just did that for the K8s dashboard, which I didn't find that useful and I'll figure out how to install it properly later, if I need/want to.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is more likely coming from the cert-manager.
You can find this from cert-manager-webhook- pod, usually in cert-manager namespace.